# Netbeans Dynamic Property Auto-Complete

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-7, phpdoc

I am writing a framework, and I have a part where I load MySQL classes into an array like this:

```
protected $db = array();
....
public function __construct(){
    $this->db   = (object)$this->db;
}
....
private function setupDatabases(){
    if(isset($this->config["databases"])){
        foreach($this->config["databases"] as $name => $data){
            $this->db->$name = $this->mysql->init($this->config);
            $this->db->$name->setConnectionParams($data);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to add some phpDoc to the code so auto-complete will suggest a list of methods in the class: `$this->db->localhost->`

I have tried may different methods of doing this but they don't work. Is there some sort of phpDoc markup where I can do this? Is this even possible?

Comment: I asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267706/phpdoc-and-code-completion-via-t-object-operator-in-netbeans-8-0) It is possible i just believe that it can not be completely dynamic...If you examine/test the example source you will have a workable solution.

Comment: I will add my question as your answer...

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to wrap that $db property itself into a class.  That way, $db->localhost becomes a class property that you can give a datatype to via the VAR tag (`@var MyDbClass`).

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Well, an example will get large ;-)  In order to have any autocomplete ability, the inner element of something will have to be documented.  Your example appears to rely on casting an array into a stdClass object.  My suggestion was to replace that stdClass with a MyDbClass that you write.  Inside MyDbClass, you definitively define its class properties, like $name and $localhost, and give each one an `@var` tag to denote its datatype.  It is this `@var` that makes the autocomplete possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to set the variables in the parent class to get code completion to pass-through. If this can be done without presetting variables please answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23267706/phpdoc-and-code-completion-via-t-object-operator-in-netbeans-8-0).

```
<?php
/**
 * This is a parent class.
 * 
 * @package Examples/doubledVars
 */
class parentExample 
{   
    public $cc;
    // notice^ <------------------------------------------------------SEE ME

    /**
     * A basic contructor
     */
    public function __construct() 
    { 
        echo '::PE Class initiated::';  
        $this -> c = 'we are value "c"  in the parent class'; 
    }
} 


/**
 * This is an Example of no doubling occuring due to __construct()
 * @see noDouble
 * 
 * @package Examples/codeCompletion
 */
class codeCompletion extends parentExample 
{  
    /**
     * @see noDouble::__construct()
     */
    public function __construct() 
    { 
        //empty constructor prevents doubling
    }


    public function getC() 
    { 
        return $this -> c; 
    } 
}



$parentExampleCC = new parentExample;

$parentExampleCC->cc = new codeCompletion;

echo $parentExampleCC->cc->getC();//CC working <------------SEE ME
```